# Checking a Public Key in canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace

Tags: iphone, ios, cryptography, public-key

I have been asked to check the public key against a known value in `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` ( a delegate callback of [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) )

This is what I have so far:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
        canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
    {
        SecKeyRef publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey([protectionSpace serverTrust]);

        NSLog(@"%@",SecTrustCopyPublicKey([protectionSpace serverTrust])); 
        return YES;
}
```

How can I compare the public key against a known value?

The NSLog produces: `<SecKeyRef: 0x687c000>` which isn't vary useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incase anyone cares, the solution was to check the certificatie byte for byte with a certificate saved on the bundle.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace 
{
    SecTrustRef trust = [protectionSpace serverTrust];

    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0);

    NSData* ServerCertificateData = (NSData*) SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);

    // Check if the certificate returned from the server is identical to the saved certificate in
    // the main bundle
    BOOL areCertificatesEqual = ([ServerCertificateData 
                                  isEqualToData:[MyClass getCertificate]]);

    [ServerCertificateData release];

    if (!areCertificatesEqual) 
    {    
        NSLog(@"Bad Certificate, canceling request");
        [connection cancel];
    }

    // If the certificates are not equal we should not talk to the server;
    return areCertificatesEqual;
}
```

Comment: Nice! How do you store the certificate to be compared? Or do you compare just a hash values?

Comment: @joshis Its stored on the bundle as a .cer file.  I used NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:.  The `[MyClass getCertificate]` is a connivence method that returns the certificates as NSData.

Comment: ... you are right - forgot we talk about the public key here and there is no need to obscure the key...

Comment: Thanks. It works. I loaded the certificate from the bundle during startup, and make the NSData of SecCertificateCopyData available in memory because I have constant connection with https

Comment: Word of warning... If you even need to update the certificate (e.g. if it expired) then this check will fail.  I think its more future proof to just check the domain or the issuer, not sure how to do that tho.

Comment: Checking the certificate - byte for byte - won't work for Google (et al). Google pins their public keys, and rotates their certificates regularly. You must perform the check against the public key.

Answer (score 4):

Note that SecCertificateCopyData returns the certificate in it's "DER" form, Distinguished Encoding Rules. So you need to incorporate the certificate in your App in that form, and not as a pem or whatever format. To convert a certificate to DER with openssl use the command: openssl x509 -in server.crt -out server.der -outform DER