# How to check ssl certificate of https request on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, https, uiwebview, certificate

I am making an iPhone app with the aim of connecting to a wifi hotspot.
The connection to the hotspot is made with a https web page.
In order to identify if the web page is a real hotspot, not a fake hotspot to steal logins, I want to check the https certificate of the web page. The web page is loaded in a UIWebview.

**Questions : How I can retreive informations about the https certificate ?**

EDIT : I think that should be possible with the `NSURLConnection` but with a UIWebView, I haven't the NSURLConnection object.

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Every cert is signed. Do you want to keep a list of trustworthy signers?

Comment: Yes, I already have the signature of the true cert, so juste compare the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a `UIWebView`, but you can using the `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` delegate method for `NSURLConnection`. You can use this delegate method to create an `NSData` copy of the certificate you want to verify, and then compare it against a locally stored copy.

That said, as indicated above it doesn't really add much security, and there are better ways of achieving what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I have also find this solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675808/